# Why is the Azure Devops API telling me that I must have these parameters for my Push request when I already do?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to make a Git push request to our Azure Devops server via the API. The address is https://MYSITE.visualstudio.com/MYPROJECT/_apis/git/repositories/2b34d4f7-2c1f-42e7-8861-u0ba34f72b40/pushes?api-version=5.1 and the body is as follows:

```
{
  "commits": [
    {
      "comment": "Just a dummy commit",
      "changes": [
        {
          "changeType": "edit",
          "item": {
            "path": "/src/MYPROJECT/MYPROJECT.csproj"
          },
          "newContent": {
            "content": "beans",
            "contentType": "rawText"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "refUpdates": [
    {
      "name": "refs/heads/TestDummyPRs/upgradeProjectToLatest",
      "oldObjectId": "058da4f3328cb1048cb43faf3b5158bc3b025615"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Web Request Failed after 4 attempts. Request: https://MYSITE.visualstudio.com/MYPROJECT/_apis/git/repositories/2b34d4f7-2c1f-42e7-8861-u0ba34f72b40/pushes?api-version=5.1. Status: BadRequest. Response: Invalid status code [BadRequest]. Response: {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"The parameters are incorrect. A posted push must contain exactly one commit and one refUpdate.\r\nParameter name: newPush","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebServer.InvalidArgumentValueException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebServer","typeKey":"InvalidArgumentValueException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}
```

"A posted push must contain exactly one commit and one refUpdate" doesn't seem entirely reasonable as that's exactly what I have in my body. Does anybody know what might be going on here?

Note that I am having no issues making other web requests, such as creating branches or retrieving file contents.

I expected my web request to proceed smoothly, and to create a Push containing the specified commit to the specified refUpdate.

I have made a manual push for via the Azure Devops web interface and caught the network traffic, and I grabbed the following JSON request out of it:

```
{
  "commits": [
    {
      "changes": [
        {
          "changeType": 2,
          "item": {
            "path": "/src/MYPROJECT/MYPROJECT.csproj"
          },
          "newContent": {
            "content": "beans",
            "contentType": 0
          }
        }
      ],
      "comment": "Just a dummy commit"
    }
  ],
  "refUpdates": [
    {
      "name": ""refs/heads/TestDummyPRs/upgradeProjectToLatest",
      "oldObjectId": "058da4f3328cb1048cb43faf3b5158bc3b025615"
    }
  ]
}
```

This seems to be meaningfully identical to the Push I'm making from my code, other than the enum fields using numerical values instead of text. I have tried my code with numerical values for enums, but that didn't change anything about the error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The web request from my application was being sent with UTF-16 encoding, whereas Postman had defaulted to UTF-8 encoding. I changed my application to use UTF-8 and it worked.